# Duplicate all stored procedures with a new name

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to take all stored procedures and create them under a new name. My problem is with procedures that are called from other procedures .

To rename a procedure is no problem for me. But to change/duplicate the procedures that still reference them by their old names is a problem.

For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.getdata 
AS
BEGIN
   EXECUTE dbo.up_updatetable ;
END;
```

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect what database server you're on.

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio and TFS to check in your code, you *might* be able to use a feature called "refactoring".

Comment: Is there a tsql because I do not have it .?

Comment: I think your best bet is to script everything and change it by hand.

Comment: We are talking about ~600 procedures.

Comment: A script containing 600 procedures shouldn't be a problem for a decent text editor with Find & Replace functionality.

Answer (score 1):

How about such a little script, to generate new scripts for all procedures, replacing all old names with new names (definition and calls):

```
SELECT 
    O.Name as ProcName 
    ,REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
        M.Definition, 
            'old_proc_name_1', 'new_proc_name_1'),
            'old_proc_name_2', 'new_proc_name_2'),
            'old_proc_name_3', 'new_proc_name_3')
        -- etc.
as CreateScript 
FROM sys.sql_modules as M INNER JOIN sys.objects as O 
ON M.object_id = O.object_id 
WHERE O.type = 'P'
and O.name not like 'sp%' -- exclude special system procs
```

Then you can execute all the scripts, either by hand, or using a cursor (more prefered for hundreds of procs).

But begin with checking carefully at least a couple of scripts before executing them.